# IPad и виртуальная машина Java

Tags: ipad, java, ios, jvm

Кто-нибудь слышал об Java-машине на IPad'е? А то уж очень хочется java-код писать под IPad, а не на Objective C.

Comment: Хватит уже холиварных тем. Пишите на чем хотите.

Comment: Почему же вы решили, что это холиварная тема? Разве тут кто-то пытается сравнивать ObjC с Java? Windows vs MacOS? Что-то не вижу ни одного признака холивара.

Comment: Достаточно посмотреть на пару ответов внизу

Comment: Ну, посмотрел и ничего не увидел :)

Comment: это говорит о том что вы плохо смотрите

Comment: Это паранойя :)

Answer (score 3):

нет! и никогда не будет! забудьте! язык разработки приложений только обджект-си -  если реально смотреть на вещи - то допустить джава машину на iOS и компания потеряет деньги. поэтому никогда джава машины не будет на iOS.

Comment: Я бы не был так категоричен. OpenJDK уже готовится к выходу для MacOS. JDK для ARM существует. Надо лишь скрестить их - и результат обязательно будет. У Oracle ресурсов гораздо больше, чем было у Sun и, судя по его деятельности, Oracle не собирается хоронить Java. Так что не стоит исключать хотя бы вероятность её выхода для i*.

Comment: тем более, что Apple вряд ли сможет "запретить" oracle выпустить java для iOs)))

Comment: На JavaOne 2011 (октябрь) показывали запуск JavaFX приложения на айпаде. Для этого команда JavaFX внутри использовала JavaME виртуальную машину CDC и Apple's OpenGL Implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The iPad Guide

> Does the iPad support Java?
> No. iPhone OS 3.2 will not support Java. The iPhone does not support Java. Steve Jobs has been quoted as saying "Java's not worth building in. Nobody uses Java anymore. It's this big heavyweight ball and chain."
> Java fans should not expect Apple to reverse this long-standing decision on the iPad.

Comment: А сторонние разработчики думаете, не будут браться за такое? например, Oracle.

Comment: думаю, будут. вопрос как скоро